# Button component disappear in mobile

Tags: react-admin

In my React-Admin project I'm using the Button component to call my custom methods but it disappears in the 'sm' (mobile) breakpoint.

It depends directly from React-Admin because using the MUI Button component next to it, the MUI Button is shown in every breakpoint.

I attach the code (the 1st disappear, the 2nd always on):

```
import { Button } from 'react-admin';
import { Button as ButtonMui } from '@mui/material';
[...]
<Button onClick={() => alert('Button RA')} label='Infos' startIcon={<Info />} />
<ButtonMui onClick={() => alert('Button MUI')} startIcon={<Info />}>Infos</ButtonMui>
```

How can I show React-Admin Button component in all breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the `<Button>` component, that cannot be disabled.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Buttons.html#button):

> Responsive (displays only the icon with a tooltip on mobile) and accessible.

If you don't want that feature, I would recommend using [MUI's `<Button>`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/) directly. RA's `<Button>` is simply a wrapper around MUI's `<Button>` after all.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comment above says, just use `<Button>` from the material UI and yes all the components in react-admin are from there

```
 <Button
     variant="contained"
     type="submit"
     color="primary"
     disabled={loading}
     sx={{
        height: '40px',
        }}
 >
   {translate('resources.login.login')}
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right, in react-admin the buttons are not displayed in sm.

But the children of the buttons are. So, there's an small trick that may work depending on the use case. For example, to display the icon:

```
<Button onClick={() => alert('Button RA')} label='Infos' startIcon={<Info />}>
    <Info />
</Button>
```